# first occurrence with setInterval

Tags: javascript

I actually use that:

```
setInterval(myFunc,30000);
```

To launch the function every 30 seconds.
How can I launch the function after only 5 seconds, then every 30 sec.

Comment: Use one setTimeout and one setInterval.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then you'll need a timeout as well

```
setTimeout(function() {
    setInterval(myFunc,30000);
    myFunc();
}, 5000);
```